# Network problem isolated to this macbook air, where to look next?

Tags: macos, wifi, network, macbook-pro

Periodically, once or twice a day, I'll start to experience network issues (latency and dropped packets) on this one machine while I'm browsing:

[image: ping results]

- Other machines on the same Linksys WRT54G wireless network continue to function normally
- I've attempted shutting down all running programs that I can identify
- I've attempted disabling and re-enabling the wireless connection and reconnecting to the network

The only thing that seems to fix it is restarting the machine. So that's what I keep doing.

My best guess is I have either have something running on the machine that I haven't identified causing this issue ... or ...?

Very open to any ideas on where to look or what types of things might cause this :)

Comment: I started experiencing the the network issues again.

This time I was able to get it working again without restarting the air. I changed the channel on the linksys wrt54g from the default 6 to 11 instead. I was confident that the other machines on the network were working, but I must have been wrong. This might have been it. I will update again if problems persist.

Comment: In any case, it's clear this probably isn't specific to the mac. I'll post what I find here in case anyone finds it useful, but the original question is likely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to download and run `iStumbler` http://istumbler.net/ on your Mac.
Run it around the place where you want to work and at peek hours
of the day (where your neighbours are also using their Wi-Fi PC and
routers).

This run should give you a clear indication of which channels are
received at a high power level. You should absolutely avoid these
overloaded channels (most probably 1, 6 & 11) and pick a channel which
is either free or received at the lowest signal level *where* and *when* you work.